# jquery using $(this) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, this

Hello people here is my code below..

```
$('.first').click(function(){

$('.second').each(function(){
console($(this));
});
});
```

i want to refer `console($(this));` to `$('.first')` not the `$('.second')` .. i think we can do it through reference variable , but still not fixing :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.first').click(function(){
  var self = this;
  $('.second').each(function(){
    console($(self));
  });
});
```

or using **[jQuery.proxy()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)** method:

```
$('.first').click(function(){
  $('.second').each($.proxy(function(){
    console($(this));
  }, this));
});
```

Comment: Well, that's akward! I'll delete mine as you beat me with 6 seconds. +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.first').click(function(){
  $('.second').each(function(){
    console($(this));
  }.bind(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `this` depends on context, you could make this clearer by being explicit about what you expect `this` to be:

```
$('.first').click(function(){
  var first = this;
  $('.second').each(function(){
    console($(first));
  });
});
```

Comment: You've got a typo: `first` and `fist`